# clicking button with selenium giving an error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from this website [link](https://www.bountou1x2.com/sport.jsp?ispt=null)

This is my code:

```
     from selenium import webdriver 
     from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
     from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
     from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
     from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
     import time
     
     driver = webdriver.Edge("C:/Users/Hamita/Documents/msedgedriver.exe")
     
     driver.get("https://www.bountou1x2.com/sport.jsp?ispt=null")
     
     
                                 
     
     WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"iframe-alto-sinistra\"]")))
     
     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"left-menu-container\"]/div[1]/div[1]"))).click()
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
```

The button i want to click is to select `Today`, it's located in the left side

Help is appreciated, thanks to all of you

Comment: What is the button name?

Comment: the button name is today

Comment: What code line is you getting the `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` exception for?

Comment: When i call the click event, last line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<iframe>` you are trying to switch to is located by the following ID `receiver`
So you should use:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"receiver")))
```

instead of

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"iframe-alto-sinistra\"]")))
```

Comment: So how can i resolve this? i deleted that line of code but still giving the same error

Comment: I found the problem. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, again thank you, you are a real Prophet

Comment: No, I just have about 6 years with Selenium, so it's just a kind of Hands On :)